# sql query timeout when using parameters in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

For some reason when I use parameters in my sql query in C# it is way slower than when I do it in SSMS, it is so slow in C# that it times out. It becomes slow when I use my parameters.

```
string occurencesQuery = @"SELECT Date, Organization, [User], Browser,  ClientVersion, ServerVersion, Server FROM cloud.ErrorLog
                                    WHERE Date BETWEEN @day AND @endDay AND
                                    Message_index LIKE @message
                                    ORDER BY Date DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(occurencesQuery, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@message", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = message;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@day", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = day;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@endDay", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDay;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the data types specified as parameters match what is actually in the database? A type conversion could slow things down quite a bit. Are you sure you query the same database in both cases? Double-check your connection string.

Comment: Take a look at OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature/

Comment: The `occurencesQuery` appears to wrap across multiple lines and yet you aren't ending each line with double quotes and adding it to the next line.  Either the string needs to be all on one line, or you need to end each line with `<space> " +` (notice the space before the double quotes) in order to concat the lines together.  You should also remove the initial `@` before your string so you aren't suppressing errors.

Comment: try this instead:  
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@message", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
 cmd.Parameters["@message"].Value = message;
 
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@day", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = day;
 cmd.Parameters["@day"].Value=day;
 
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@endDay", SqlDbType.DateTime);
 cmd.Parameters["@endDay"].Value = endDay

Comment: run sqlprofiler to show you what sql is receiving and how its processing it.  If the reason does jump out at you then copy/paste the query from SQL Profiler into SSMS and view the query plan.

Comment: Is it a command timeout or a connection timeout?

Comment: I believe this detailed article by Erland Sommarskog will help you understand what is going on: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same Problem. The problem was fixed when the database was shrinked.

Comment: this is old question. Ali Gunturk

Comment: @CodeMind I think you misunderstand how Stackoverflow works, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265642/6089612, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23996/370318, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185181/370318, ... Having said that, @Ali this answer has a lot of room for improvement - what do you mean `shrinked`? How did you do that, exactly? Think of others with this same problem visiting in 1 year's time - a good answer tells them all they need to solve it.